# Create Properties file in Dynamic web project?

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, properties

Hi all i am trying to create a properties file dynamically in my code as

```
package abc.in;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Properties;

public class DBConnection {
    OutputStream out = null;

    public void SetAllProps() {
        try {

            Properties props = new Properties();

            File f = new File("myApp.properties");
            if (f.exists()) {

                props.load(new FileReader(f));
                // Change your values here
                props.setProperty("ServerAddress", "ThatNewCoolValue");
            } else {

                // Set default values?
                props.setProperty("ServerAddress", "DullDefault");
                props.setProperty("ServerPort", "8080");
                props.setProperty("ThreadCount", "456");

                f.createNewFile();
            }

            out = new FileOutputStream(f);
            props.store(out, "This is an optional header comment string");

            System.out.println(props.get("ServerPort"));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

            if (out != null) {

                try {

                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {

                    System.out
                            .println("IOException: Could not close myApp.properties output stream; "
                                    + ex.getMessage());
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I fi do this in java project then it creates a property file with the above name "myApp.properties" but when i execute the same code in dynamic web project, it doesn't create any properties file. What am i doing wrong. Looking forward to your answers. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `f.getAbsolutePath()` to get the absolute path of the property file you have created.